# Internet Explorer 8 is blocking CSS, JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I'm in the process of developing a website that makes use of JQuery's superfish. Now if I want to test it in Internet Explorer 8 I'm getting the message`To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer` in firefox everything runs smoothly. My code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>site</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superfish.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/superfish-navbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function(){
         $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
             delay:         0,
             speed:         'fast',
             autoArrows:    false,
             dropShadows:   false,
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
```

if I remove the following code it works fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superfish.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/superfish-navbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function(){
             $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
                 delay:         0,
                 speed:         'fast',
                 autoArrows:    false,
                 dropShadows:   false,
            });
        });

    </script>
```

if I only leave in the first css line I'm getting the error again, thus leaving only

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
```

Are there any solutions to this? I don't want my visitors to click on allow everytime the access the site ;-( Clueless here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect this is because you are running this script locally. IE blocks scripts (and I guess CSS, which can run scripts with `expression`) for web pages on the hard drive in order to help stop viruses.

Try uploading it to a remote server, or setting up a web server at `http://localhost/`. You probably shouldn't have those issues once not using `file:\\\`. You can also change your local intranet security settings to prevent these warnings, but I'd recommend against it; they're set by default for a reason. Your call.

Comment: Yip, that was the problem, I ran the files from a Flash Drive. I copied it over to a web server and it seemed to solve the issue. Thank you. Much apprecaited

Comment: @Roland: Glad to help :) Make sure you click on the check mark next to an answer if it answered your question! (But also see Andy E...'s head's answer before you do - that might be a quicker solution, depending on your needs.)

Comment: I usually always work on a web server, was to lazy to copy the files over, but now it's done.

Comment: Though I wonder why the recommendation is to not change the relevant security settings when no other browser implements such security settings anyway?

Comment: @PandaWood: meh. I'm not comfortable recommending that someone specifically *lower* the security of their device when there's another acceptable solution out there. Besides, perhaps IE has these policies where other browsers don't because it's historically been more vulnerable to Javascript attacks than other browsers :/ Regardless, if you feel like the default policy is too paranoid, go for it :)

Answer (score 6):

Running the site in the local zone is what's causing your problem.  If you want to continue testing locally, you can use a [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx):

```
<!-- saved from url=(0022)http://www.example.com/ -->
```

*The parenthesized number should be 4 digits specifying the length of the URL.*

This will force IE to run the site in the security zone that applies to the domain specified.  Just remember to remove it when you upload your site for production, although leaving it in would have no detrimental effect.